# Explain limit points in complex analysis relating to Coincidence Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am doing a complex analysis module and I got lost at some point after limit points were mentioned.

More importantly, I dont understand how it relates to the following lemma.

The lemma is :
Suppose f is analytic on open disc Dr with radius R. If Z_0 is a limit point of the set {z in Dr: f(z) = 0}
Then f(z) = 0 for all z in Dr.

Does anyone have a proof or intuitive explanaition for this lemma cause its confusing me:(

Another question it was used to solve was:
Does there exist a function f such that f(1/k) = f(-1/k) = 1/k^3
The answer uses accumulation points of sets to conclude no but i dont understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction if $f$ is not constant, then each fiber $f^{-1}(x_0)$ is a closed and discrete set of $D_r$, so in particular $f^{-1}(0)$ is closed and discrete and it is not possible because $z_0$ is a limit point for the set.
In fact $z_0\in f^{-1}(0)$ because it is closed and there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that

$U/\{0\}\cap f^{-1}(0)=\emptyset$

because of $f^{-1}(0)$ is discrete and it is not possible because $z_0$ is a limit point for the set.
This result is true for each open set of the conplex plane.

By contradiction you have that there exists an analytic $f$ such that $f(\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{k^3}$, so

$g(z):=f(z)-\frac{1}{z^3}$ that is defined in $D_1/\{0\}$ is an analytic function that is zero for each $z=\frac{1}{k}$
Thus you have that $0$ is a limit point for $g^{-1}(0)$ that means

$g=0$ so $f=\frac{1}{z^3}$ in $D_1/\{0\}$.

This is not possible because there is not analytic function on $D_1$ that coincide with $\frac{1}{z^3}$ on $D_1/\{0\}$.